# Massive performance loss with glMapBuffer()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I found out that mapping a buffer with write access, no matter with glMapBuffer, glMapBufferARB or glMapBufferRange, I will always get an enormous FPS drop.

Everything had worked as usual until I mapped the buffer and unmapped it right afterwards. It made no difference whether the buffer was mapped while drawing or whether the buffer has long been unmapped again, I always get a huge performance loss. The FPS drop is also there when I map only one float (4 Bytes) and not the whole buffer.

I ran the code with different GPU’s and here are the results with 1024 * 1024 quads:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti:

  - Without mapping the buffer: ~1100 FPS
  - With mapping the buffer:  ~200 FPS
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070:

  - Without mapping the buffer: ~800 FPS
  - With mapping the buffer: ~40 FPS
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060:

  - Without mapping the buffer: ~800 FPS
  - With mapping the buffer: ~200 FPS
- NVIDIA GeForce MX150:

  - Without mapping the buffer: ~160 FPS
  - With mapping the buffer: ~30 FPS
- Intel UHD Graphics 620:

  - Without mapping the buffer: ~140 FPS
  - With mapping the buffer: ~140 FPS

As you can see on every NVIDIA GPU where I ran the program I got massive performance drops with glMapBuffer (on RTX 2070 the framerate is only 1/20 of the usual framerate) however, on the Intel UHD Graphics 620 I got no performance issues at all.

I use:

- OpenGL 4.6
- glew 2.1.0
- glfw 2.7

Now I have several questions:

- Why is there such an FPS drop?
- Why is it only on the NVIDIA GPU’s and not on the Intel Graphics?
- Can’t NVIDIA handle buffers that are or where mapped?
- Might that be a bug in the library?
- Did I something wrong, missed I something out?
- Is there a way to fix it or a work around?

Here is the code of my test program:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#define WIN_WIDTH 1500
#define WIN_HEIGHT 900
#define WIN_POS_X 300
#define WIN_POS_Y 10

#define M_PI 3.14159265359

#define SPEED                   100     // moving speed
#define ROTATION_SENSETIVITY    0.002f  // mouse sensetivity

#define SQRT_QUAD_COUNT         1024    // num quads: 1024 * 1024
#define QUAD_SPACE              0.2f    // Space between quads

uint32_t atXY(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t xSize)
{
    return y*xSize + x;
}

void gen_shaders(uint32_t& shader_program)
{
    std::string vertex_shader_code      =   "#version 460 core\n"
                                            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                            "uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
                                            "void main()\n"
                                            "{\n"
                                            "   gl_Position = MVP * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);\n"
                                            "}\0";

    std::string fragment_shader_code    =   "#version 460 core\n"
                                            "out vec4 outColor;\n"
                                            "void main()\n"
                                            "{\n"
                                            "   outColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
                                            "}\0";

    const char* hilfe1 = vertex_shader_code.c_str();
    const char* hilfe2 = fragment_shader_code.c_str();

    uint32_t vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &hilfe1, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    uint32_t fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &hilfe2, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(shader_program);

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
}

void initWindow(int xsize, int ysize, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    if(!glfwOpenWindow(xsize, ysize, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }
    glfwSetWindowPos(xpos, ypos);
}

void gen_vertices(std::vector<float>& vertices)
{
    for(int y=0; y<SQRT_QUAD_COUNT; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<SQRT_QUAD_COUNT; x++)
        {
            const float posx = (1.0f + QUAD_SPACE) * x;
            const float posy = (1.0f + QUAD_SPACE) * y;

            const float curr_vertices[12] = {
                        posx,         posy, 10.0f,
                1.0f +  posx,         posy, 10.0f,
                1.0f +  posx, 1.0f +  posy, 10.0f,
                        posx, 1.0f +  posy, 10.0f

            };

            for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
                vertices.push_back(curr_vertices[i]);
        }
    }
}
void mouse_action(int sx, int sy, double& rotx, double& roty, float sensetivity)
{
    constexpr double roty_max = 89.9/180.0*M_PI;
    const int sx_half = sx / 2;
    const int sy_half = sy / 2;

    int mx, my;
    glfwGetMousePos(&mx, &my);

    const int deltax = sx_half - mx;
    const int deltay = sy_half - my;

    rotx += deltax * sensetivity;
    roty += deltay * sensetivity;

    if(rotx >= 2*M_PI)
        rotx -= 2*M_PI;
    else if(rotx <= -2*M_PI)
        rotx += 2*M_PI;

    if(roty > roty_max)
        roty = roty_max;
    else if(roty < -roty_max)
        roty = -roty_max;

    glfwSetMousePos(sx_half, sy_half);
}

void move_action(double& posx, double& posy, double& posz, double rotx, float speed)
{
    static double old_time = glfwGetTime();
    double deltatime = glfwGetTime() - old_time;
    old_time = glfwGetTime();

    if(glfwGetKey('W') == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        posx += speed * deltatime * sin(rotx);
        posz += speed * deltatime * cos(rotx);
    }
    if(glfwGetKey('A') == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        posx += speed * deltatime * sin(rotx + M_PI / 2);
        posz += speed * deltatime * cos(rotx + M_PI / 2);
    }
    if(glfwGetKey('S') == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        posx += speed * deltatime * sin(rotx + M_PI);
        posz += speed * deltatime * cos(rotx + M_PI);
    }
    if(glfwGetKey('D') == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        posx += speed * deltatime * sin(rotx + M_PI * 1.5);
        posz += speed * deltatime * cos(rotx + M_PI * 1.5);
    }
    if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        posy += speed * deltatime;
    if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LSHIFT) == GLFW_PRESS)
        posy -= speed * deltatime;
}

int main()
{
    int width, height;
    bool running = true;

    glfwInit();
    initWindow(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, WIN_POS_X, WIN_POS_Y);
    glfwSetMousePos(WIN_WIDTH/2, WIN_HEIGHT/2);
    glfwDisable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR);
    glewInit();
    glfwSwapInterval(0);

    uint32_t shader_program;
    uint32_t vao, vbo;

    std::vector<float> vertices;

    double posx = 0.0;
    double posy = 0.0;
    double posz = 0.0;
    double rotx = 0.0;
    double roty = 0.0;

    gen_shaders(shader_program);    // generate the shaders
    gen_vertices(vertices);         // generate the vertex data

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao); // generate vao
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);      // generate vbo

    // bind both
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);   // fill buffer with vertex data
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), NULL);   // set attribute pointer ( 0 )

    // in this #if - #endif - block are the 2 lines of code that cause the problem / FPS drop:
    #if 1
    void* ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY); // <----- map the buffer

    if(ptr == NULL) // does not return with -1
        return -1;

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER); // <------ unmap the buffer

    if(glGetError() != 0)   // does not return with -2
        return -2;
    #endif

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    int frames = 0;
    clock_t time = clock();
    while(running)
    {
        // get fps
        if(clock() - time >= 1000)
        {
            std::cout << frames << std::endl;
            time = clock();
            frames = 0;
        }

        glfwGetWindowSize(&width, &height);
        height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mouse_action(width, height, rotx, roty, ROTATION_SENSETIVITY);
        move_action(posx, posy, posz, rotx, SPEED);

        glUseProgram(shader_program);
        glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projection              = glm::perspective(glm::radians(100.0f), (float)width/(float)height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        glm::mat4 view                    = glm::lookAt(glm::dvec3(posx, posy, posz), glm::dvec3(posx+cos(roty)*sin(rotx), posy+sin(roty), posz+cos(rotx)*cos(roty)), glm::dvec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

        uint32_t mvp_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "MVP");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection * view * model));

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices.size() / 3); // draw everything
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glUseProgram(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();
        frames++;

        // exit if ESC was pressed or window was closed
        running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader_program);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably fast on the Intel GPUs because the Intel GPU uses the same memory chips as your CPU, and the nVidia GPU doesn't. Have you tested whether there's different performance with different mapping modes? Also, you should be measuring the difference with milliseconds per frame, not FPS.

Comment: Perhaps this _"... For example, such mappings may be marked as uncacheable regions of memory, and in such cases reading from them may be very slow. To ensure optimal performance, the client should use the mapping in a fashion consistent with the values of GL_BUFFER_USAGE for the buffer object and of access. Using a mapping in a fashion inconsistent with these values is liable to be __multiple orders of magnitude slower__ than using normal memory."_ https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml

Comment: Your time measurement is completely broken, The `clock` function is supposed to return used CPU time with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` tic rate, not wall clock time in milliseconds, although microsoft uses a non-conforming implementation that does. Apart from that nvidia's GL debug output is very verbose about where it places or moves a buffer. So the guess would be that the driver puts this memory into host RAM instead of video memory, which would be cionsitent both your usage hint and the usage pattern your driver will see.

Comment: Btw, I don't see any difference in performance on a GTX 1060.

Comment: Check if `glUnmapBuffer` returns `false` before unconditionally calling `glGetError`.

Comment: Now I have changed my time measurement to ms / frame using timer queries (I hope that was right way to do this) and rendering still takes 5 times as long. On my GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 1080 Ti: without mapping the buffer 0.9 ms / frame, with mapping the buffer 4.7 ms / frame.

I tried different modes of mapping but without success (I always get around 4.7 – 4.8 ms / frame) and glUnmapBuffer doesn’t return false.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem? If possible with an example code?

Comment: Start at looking at your driver's messages from gl debug output.

Comment: Debugging helped me to find the cause of the problem: before mapping, the GPU uses the video memory and after mapping, it uses the system RAM and keeps using the RAM after I unmapped the buffer. Can I force the GPU to use the video memory again?